# CSS: search box will be automatically resize base on windows size using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to design a layout as below image:

[image: layout]

As in this layout, this is my header. Black rectangle is some components (buttons, link ...) with fixed width, and red rectangle is my search form.

I want when user changes the size of browser windows, search form will be smaller (in width), until some value, will appear horizontal scrollbar. Maybe the hard part is: I don't know how to solve "auto-resize" in css.

Here is my sample code:

my HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">
    <script src="javascripts/pace.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="page-head">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <form class="form-search" action="#" onsubmit="return false" method="get" name="search_form">
                <div class="search-box"></div>  
            </form>
            <nav class="site-nav">
                <span><a href="/" class="site-nav__home"></a></span>
                <div class="site-nav__item">Home</div>
                <div class="site-nav__item">Notifications</div>
                <div class="site-nav__item">Profile</div>
                <div class="site-nav__button">Add Question</div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body> 
</html>
```

my CSS:

```
.html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.page-head {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.page-head.wrapper {
    width: 1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;     
    /* center horizontally. apply for block level element */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
    /* drop shadow effect */
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
    height: 45px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

form {
    display: block;
}

.logo {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: red;
}
.form-search {
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    position: static;
    height: 27px;
    background-image: url(../images/search.png);
}

.search-box {
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 27px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    background: #eee;
}

.site-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;

}

.site-nav__item {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Please tell me how to design this layout using CSS. And if possible, how can do by using Flexbox ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? unfortunately SO users can't help you without further research into the subject or attempts of your own. Where is your issue when implementing this component?

Comment: @BIW I have edited may question, including code i'm working on. thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flexbox works well to solve this issue.  You basically want the search box (or its form element) to fill available space and shrink as needed (up to a certain point) when the window size decreases.

[image: Gif of flexbox behavior during window resizing]

The secret sauce is to give the form element a `flex-grow: 1` to tell it to fill the available space.

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;   
}
.page-head {
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;  /* Makes the nav items and logo appear vertically centered with the search box*/
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

.logo {
  /* Prevent logo from shrinking 
     so it doesn't collide when window gets narrow. */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.search-form {
  margin: 0 1rem;  
  flex-grow: 1; /* <-- THE SECRET SAUCE! */
  min-width: 18rem;
}

.search-box {
  width: 100%;  
  padding: .4rem;
  background-color: #ffb;
}

.site-nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
.site-nav__item {  
  /* Prevent nav items from shrinking 
     so they won't collide when window gets narrow. */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 .55rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Prevent multi-word nav items from wrapping. */
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

```html
<header class="page-head">
 
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>

  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" class="search-box" 
           placeholder="Search   (this form fills available space)">
  </form>

  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="site-nav__item">Home</li>
      <li class="site-nav__item">Notifications</li>
      <li class="site-nav__item">Profile</li>
      <li class="site-nav__item">Add Question</li>      
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, I prefer using tables because they already have most of the required styles - even if it does add a lot of html. I decided it would be best to create a template and let you change things as necessary:

```css
#header{
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  table-layout:auto;
}
#header img{
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
}
#header form{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  min-width:200px;
}
#header input{
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
}
#header nav{
  float:right;
  display:inline-table;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#header a{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table id="header">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img id="logo"/>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 100%;">
   <form>
    <input type="text" name ="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
   </form>
  </td>
  <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
   <nav> 
    <a href="#">Home</a>  
    <a href="#">Notifications</a>
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
    <a href="#">Add question</a>
   </nav>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Apologies, I tried keeping my structure as similar to yours as I could but there are a fair few differences. In any case, I hope this helps!